# Neural networks or Deep learning on Item based Collaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, recommender-system

I have data in the form of grocery item Name, grocery item ID and their respective order ID's. Please find the sample data below :

```
ItemName   ItemID   OrderID
Apple       123     1001
Sugar       092     1001
Knife       112     9890
Spoons      232     9890
Buttercups  234     9890
Ketchup     545     7867
Bottle      787     7867
eggs        543     7867
apple       123     7867
```

I want to build a recommend-er system where a guest user will be shown items which best matches the item in his current cart depending on the algorithm which sees the past history of items which are frequently bought together .

I have already applied priori rules algorithm so I am looking to build a neural network so as to recommend the best matching grocery.

I have done research , there is not much information related to this or codes on internet,
where should i start or can any one build neural network using some random data or help me to get to the right way ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are your data, and what is your desired output? Do you already have past items bought together? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes I already have transaction data of the items being bought together. 
I want output as set of rules like if a user buy { Knife,Spoons } together , then he should be recommended butter cups . I have applied association rules which gave me a correct output  but i need to build a neural network to have the association rules